# Calling functions from js but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, forms, function

I wrote code inside a form tag, when the user clicks on the radio button, courses should appear and these courses are related to their major,
it was working fine, but when I put the form tag it doesn't work anymore.
I used the form tag because of PHP.

JavaScript:

```html
<script>
  function cs() {
    if (document.getElementById("cs").checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("isco").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cnco").style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("csco").style.display = "initial";
  }

  function is() {
    if (document.getElementById("is").checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("csco").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("cnco").style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("isco").style.display = "initial";
  }

  function cn() {
    if (document.getElementById("cn").checked == true) {
      document.getElementById("isco").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("csco").style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById("cnco").style.display = "initial";
  }
</script>

div style="background-color: white; text-align: left; padding-left:100px; padding-bottom: 10px">
<br><br><br>
<h3>Sign up</h3>

<form id="sign" name="sign" method="POST" action="sign.php">

  <label for="major">Major:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="major" id="cs" value="cs" onclick="cs()">CS
  <input type="radio" name="major" id="is" value="is" onclick="is()">IS
  <input type="radio" name="major" id="cn" value="cn" onclick="cn()">CN

  <div style="display:  none;" id="csco">
    <label for="courses">Select the courses you finished or takes currently: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="pr">Professional Responsibility
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="se">Software Engineering
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="alg">Analysis and Design of Algorithms
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="web">Web-based Systems
    <br>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" id="isco">
    <label for="courses">Select the courses you finished or takes currently: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="web">Web-based Systems
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="sad">System Analysis and Design(2)
    <br>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" id="cnco">
    <label for="courses">Select the courses you finished or takes currently: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="np">Introduction to Network Programming.
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="nd">Network Design or Network Simulation and Modeling.
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>

  <button name="sig" id="sig" style="padding: 10px">Sign up</button>

</form>
</div>
```

is there any way to make the JavaScript work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, avoid adding listeners direct in the html. Always try to add them by script.

The below code works. Look that I added the `onclick` listeners inside the JS script, using 
`document.getElementById("elementId").onclick = functionToAssign`
 (function name without parentheses in this case).

Don't forget to remove the `onclick` from HTML.

Your current code is not working probably because that when HTML is rendered, the functions are not yet defined.

```js
function cs() {
  if (document.getElementById("cs").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("isco").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("cnco").style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById("csco").style.display = "initial";
}
document.getElementById("cs").onclick = cs

function is() {
  if (document.getElementById("is").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("csco").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("cnco").style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById("isco").style.display = "initial";
}
document.getElementById("is").onclick = is

function cn() {
  if (document.getElementById("cn").checked == true) {
    document.getElementById("isco").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("csco").style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById("cnco").style.display = "initial";
}
document.getElementById("cn").onclick = cn
```

```html
<div style="background-color: white; text-align: left; padding-left:100px; padding-bottom: 10px">
<br><br><br>
<h3>Sign up</h3>

<form id="sign" name="sign" method="POST" action="sign.php">

  <label for="major">Major:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="major" id="cs" value="cs">CS
  <input type="radio" name="major" id="is" value="is">IS
  <input type="radio" name="major" id="cn" value="cn">CN


  <div style="display:  none;" id="csco">
    <label for="courses">Select the courses you finished or takes currently: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="pr">Professional Responsibility
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="se">Software Engineering
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="alg">Analysis and Design of Algorithms
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="web">Web-based Systems
    <br>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" id="isco">
    <label for="courses">Select the courses you finished or takes currently: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="web">Web-based Systems
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="sad">System Analysis and Design(2)
    <br>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none;" id="cnco">
    <label for="courses">Select the courses you finished or takes currently: </label>
    <br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="np">Introduction to Network Programming.
    <input type="checkbox" name="courses" value="nd">Network Design or Network Simulation and Modeling.
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>

  <button name="sig" id="sig" style="padding: 10px">Sign up</button>

</form>
</div>
```

Comment: where should i put the script tag? i try the code in my editor put it does not work, but when i run it here , it work!

Comment: You really need the script inside the html as a tag? Can't you use a external JS file? If you really want to use the script inside HTML, add it as you are adding before, just substitute your current code by the one I have above, it must work. **(try it using the `<script>` after the HTML)**